# UITextField within UITableViewCell using auto layout

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, autolayout

I have a `UITableViewController` which displays one section and one cell (test case).
Within that cell I have a `UITextField` which should span the length of the cell's `contentView` with 20 points on either side (i.e. `H:|-20-[field]-20-|`) and be centered vertically.
When I use a nib with the necessary constraints it works perfectly, but when I add the constraints programmatically it seems to follow none of them. (See images.)

The `NSLog()`'s in `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` print exactly the same constraints for both cases.

**FOOAppDelegate.m:**

```
#import "FOOAppDelegate.h"
#import "FOORootViewController.h"

@implementation FOOAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[FOORootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]];
    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

@end
```

**FOORootViewController.m:** (Note: is declared as UITextFieldDelegate)

```
#import "FOORootViewController.h"

enum { kFOOTextFieldTag = 0xFEED /* Arbitrary. */ };

@implementation FOORootViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        self.title = @"Foo";
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FooCell";
    /* Uncomment the following line when using nib. */
    //[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FooCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    /* Comment this if block when using nib. */
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    /* Comment this if block when using nib. */
    if (self.editing && ([cell.contentView viewWithTag:kFOOTextFieldTag] == nil)) {
        UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        field.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
        field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
        field.delegate = self;
        field.placeholder = @"New";
        field.tag = kFOOTextFieldTag;
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        field.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:field];

        NSDictionary *objs = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell.contentView, field);
        cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-7-[field]"
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:objs]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[field]-6-|"
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:objs]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[field]"
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:objs]];
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[field]-20-|"
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:objs]];
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kFOOTextFieldTag];
    if (self.editing) {
        field.hidden = NO;

        NSLog(@"field: %@", field);
    } else {
        field.hidden = YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"cell.contentView: %@", cell.contentView);
    NSLog(@"constraints: %@", cell.contentView.constraints);
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}
```

This is what I'm getting when not using the nib (no difference when in landscape):
[image: Programmatic auto layout]

And this is what I get with the nib (scales appropriately for landscape):
[image: IB auto layout]

Comment: I had a similar issue with cell constraints and resolved it by setting the constraints in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: instead of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.  It seems they were acting on values that were not fully initialized yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete this line, and it will work properly:

```
cell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

You only need to set that to NO for subviews that you add yourself.

Also, I noticed that you register the nib in cellForRowAtIndexPath (if you're using a nib) -- you shouldn't do that, since cellForRowAtIndexPath is called many times. You should put that code in viewDidLoad.

Another thing -- you should simplify your constraint code. The big advantage of using the visual format language is that you can set multiple constraints in the same statement, so you can combine your 4 statements into 2:

```
cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-7-[field]-6-|"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:nil
                                          views:objs]];

cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                                          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[field]-20-|"
                                          options:0
                                          metrics:nil
                                          views:objs]];
```